# zoom meeting with cron

Tags: cron, xvfb, zoom

My zoom class teacher doesn't give us a link with a hashed password and I am using [this](https://github.com/tmonfre/zoom-cli) to open zoom from command line. (**EDIT:** Later I knew that normal zoom command open a link with non-hashed password.)

Now I am even sick of typing the command in a terminal, so that I want to make it a cron job. My script (`/home/taro/Scripts/i_hate_cron.sh`)is like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
/usr/bin/pyzoom class101
```

Here, `pyzoom` is a symbolic link to the afore-hyperlinked python program that opens a zoom meeting with automatically filling a meeting ID and a password. And the `systemctl status cronie.service` 's output is

```
4:52 yamada CROND[66411]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user taro
Feb 18 16:25:01 yamada crond[66615]: pam_unix(crond:session): session opened for user taro(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Feb 18 16:25:01 yamada CROND[66616]: (taro) CMD (/home/taro/Scripts/i_hate_cron.sh)
Feb 18 16:25:52 yamada CROND[66615]: (taro) CMDEND (/home/taro/Scripts/i_hate_cron.sh)
Feb 18 16:25:52 yamada CROND[66615]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user taro
```

`crond` didn't give me the zoom window:<
Using `xvfb` and taking a screenshot of it, I confirmed that this `cron` job works fine with it, but I don't know how to change from outputting to display `:99`, which is the default of `xvfb`, to `:0`.

What should I do to make zoom open automatically with `cron`? (Actually I prefer `systemd/Timer`, since I am using Arch Linux. So I also welcome answers adopting `systemd`)

Comment: One idea is running zoom background in the physical display. And when cron initiates zoom, it  opens a "session" in an existing one.

Comment: Cron has no notion that you are running a gui and you appear to be running a browser, not Zoom. However, why not just download & install the Zoom package, there is a native version that works well.

Comment: @Bib Is it possible to use zoom in a browser?

Comment: Yes, but it's just a web page... why bother when there is a linux zoom application which can be docked. Why not try it and if it does not work for you, then...

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant. Do you mean I am running a browser before opening a zoom? Or are you suggesting that the zoom application can open recurrent meetings with filling the password and meeting ID and without the help of cron?